# How to take key value from array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have an array like this. Now I need to create a query based on the key value and value for that key.

```
$array_value =  Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [Name] => XisN
                [Email] => xxxx@gmail.com
                [id] => XID
                [Number] => xxx@gmail.com
                [Mark] => xxxx
                [Emp_id] => 0052
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [Name] => yyyy
                [Email] => yyy@gmail.com
                [id] => 005YY
                [Number] => yyy@gmail.com
                [Mark] => yyyy
                [Emp_id] => fretw
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [Name] => zzzz
                [Email] => zzzz@gmail.com
                [id] => zzzzz
                [Number] => zzzw
                [Mark] => dfsf
                [Emp_id] => dsgsd54
            )

          ...
          ...
          ...
       )
```

Now I need to check the key value of the array and generate some query based on the key value. For example, if the key value is emp_id or id, then I need to generate some query; otherwise, if the key value is a number, then I need to create some other query.

```
if(key value is NAME)
{
    $val .= 'NAME = XisN'; 
}else(key value is ID)
{
    $val .= 'ID = XID';
} else {
    $val_2 = 'Number = xxx@gmail.com'
    ..etc
}
```

This is what actually I am trying to do, but I don't know what I am doing in foreach. Please help.

```
foreach($array_value as $value)
{
   foreach ($value as $key => $colname)
   {
      if($colname =='Emp_id') {
          $dynamic_qry .= 'Emp_id ='.$colname;
      } elseif($colname =='id') {
          $dynamic_qry  .= 'id ='.$colname;
      } else {
           $dynamic_qry_2  .= $colname' = '.$colname;
      }
   }
```

Comment: You are checking **key_value** in foreach loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
foreach($array_value as $value)
{
    foreach ($value as $key => $colname)
    {
        if ($key === 'Emp_id' || $key === 'id') {
            $dynamic_qry .= $key . '=' . $colname;
        } else {
            $dynamic_qry_2  .= $key . '=' . $colname;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

List item

in your second loop $key is the column name and $colname is the value so try this

```
<?php
foreach($array_value as $value)
{
   foreach ($value as $key => $val)
    {
      if($key ==='Emp_id') {
          $dynamic_qry .= $key.'='.$val;
      }else if($key ==='id'){
          $dynamic_qry  .= $key.'='.$val;
      }else {
           $dynamic_qry_2  .= $key.'='.$val;
      }
  }
?>
```